# Get Department of user based on Fullname in Active Directory

Tags: vba, excel, active-directory

I have a list of users with full name in an excel file. I would like to automatically get their department based on their fullname by getting it from the AD.

My sheet Tabelle1 has a list of 700 plus users. In this case, I need it to be done automatically to save time.

Basically, I want to look in AD based on their full name. If their fullname matched in AD users, then in column 7, it will place the department.

I found a code but I am not sure on how I can continue:

```
Sub LoadUserInfo()
Dim x, objConnection, objCommand, objRecordSet, oUser, skip, disa
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Tabelle1 As Worksheet

' get domain
Dim oRoot
Set oRoot = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
Dim sDomain
sDomain = oRoot.Get("defaultNamingContext")
Dim strLDAP
strLDAP = "LDAP://" & sDomain

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE

objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT adsPath FROM '" & strLDAP & "' WHERE objectCategory='person'AND objectClass='user'"
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

x = 2
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
With sht

    Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
        Set oUser = GetObject(objRecordSet.Fields("aDSPath"))
        skip = oUser.sAMAccountName
        disa = oUser.AccountDisabled

        If skip = .Cells(x, 5).Value Then

        .Cells(x, 7) = oUser.Department

            DoEvents
            objRecordSet.MoveNext



Else

            DoEvents

            x = x + 1
            objRecordSet.MoveNext
        End If

    Loop

End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use filter in the query to get records for the matching user name.

---

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox GetDepartment("Stark", "Tony")
End Sub

Function GetDepartment(strLastName As String, strFirstName As String) As String

    Dim objRoot             As Object
    Dim strDomain           As String
    Dim objConn             As Object
    Dim objComm             As Object
    Dim objRecordset        As Object

    Dim sFilter             As String
    Dim sAttribs            As String
    Dim sDepth              As String
    Dim sBase               As String
    Dim sQuery              As String


    Set objRoot = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    strDomain = objRoot.Get("DefaultNamingContext")
    Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objComm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    strLastName = Replace(strLastName, Space(1), "")
    strFirstName = Replace(strFirstName, Space(1), "")
    sFilter = "(&(objectClass=person)(objectCategory=user)(givenName=" & strFirstName & ")" & "(sn=" & strLastName & "*)" & ")"

    sAttribs = "department,sAMAccountName,givenName,sn"
    sDepth = "SubTree"
    sBase = "<LDAP://" & strDomain & ">"
    sQuery = sBase & ";" & sFilter & ";" & sAttribs & ";" & sDepth

    objConn.Open "Data Source=Active Directory Provider;Provider=ADsDSOObject"
    Set objComm.ActiveConnection = objConn
    objComm.Properties("Page Size") = 40000
    objComm.CommandText = sQuery
    Set objRecordset = objComm.Execute

    Do Until objRecordset.EOF
       GetDepartment = objRecordset("department")
       Exit Function
       objRecordset.MoveNext
    Loop


End Function
```

Comment: I have tried the code above and changed Tony Stark to something that is on my list. But it only displays blank. How will I be able to make this to loop on my list of fullname and put the department for each user on the list? My sheet is called Tabelle1 and full name column is on 5th and department column is on 7th.

Comment: @Sevpoint, put some effort dude. :) That example extracts the department for the user, if its available in you ADS setup. How to loop, try to figure that out. That's simple. :)

Comment: Ok, I got it. :) Thanks a lot. I have tested few names and it was able to get the department. Now I have to do some looping. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @cyboashu i know this is an older thread, is there any way for your solution to display all users from the department name, instead of using a users first and last name?